# Invalid_request Missing grant Type VBA Error Oauth 2.0

Tags: vba, api, oauth

I'm struggling with this from last some hours.

I'm trying to receive an access token from the API of a partner via OAuth.

There's a small mistake in it that generates this error:

> "error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing grant type"

Here is the VBA code I'm using in MS Access:

```
Public Function API_MyArrow_Artikel(artikelBez) As String

    Dim objHTTP As Object
    
    Dim strHead As String, strClientId As String, strClientSecret As String, strBody As String
    
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    
    strClientId = "xxx"
    strClientSecret = "xxx"
    
    strUrl1 = "https://my.arrow.com/api/security/oauth/token"
    
    strHead = strClientId & ":" & strClientSecret
    
    lngADRNR = 674
    
    objHTTP.Open "POST", strUrl1, False
    
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "application", "x-www-form-urlencoded"
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "client_id", strClientId
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "client_secret", strClientSecret
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(strHead)
    
    'objHTTP.setRequestHeader "grant_type", "client_credentials"
    
    objHTTP.SetTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000 'Timeout (in milliseconds) to wait for timeout in each request phase (Resolve, Connect, Send, Receive)
    
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    
    objHTTP.Send "grant_type=client_credentials" 
    
    API_MyArrow_Artikel = objHTTP.responseText

End Function
```

Any sort of suggestion to resolve is really appreciated as there are only some experts of OAuth 2.0 in here.

Thanks,

Comment: try`objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded "`

Comment: @QHarr Can you please explain what is it?

Comment: What do the API docs for that site say about the request format?

Comment: https://my.arrow.com/more/developers/#section/Access-Token

Comment: Hello @Tim, Thank for showing your interest in here.

Comment: Here is the documentation Link of API  https://my.arrow.com/more/developers/#section/Access-Token

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this.

There is some error in URL which needs to be fixed by adding below code to URL:

> my.arrow.com/api/security/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials

And secondly replacing this:

```
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "application", "x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

To this:

```
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

did the Job for me.